# How can I give my JSON dictionary a main key, without implementing it into my loop?

Tags: javascript, json

I am translating some code from python into Javascript (I am inexperienced in JS), as part of it I need to write a JSON, currently when writing in JS it looks like this(just a brief sample):

```
[
  {
    "Num": "000000",
    "Status": 1,
  },
  {
    "Num": "00001",
    "Status": 0,
  },
]
```

However I need it to look like this:

```
{
    "mydata": [
        {
            "Num": "00000",
            "Status": 1,
        },
        {
            "Num": "00001",
            "Status": 0,
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I adapt my code to generate this single main key for the whole JSON, here is what I have so far:

```
var jsondata = []
for (result in results) {
    jsondata.push({

        'Num' : idnum,      
        'Status': results[result].StatusID,  
    })
}

let data = JSON.stringify(jsondata, null, 2)
fs.writeFileSync('testingjson.json', data)
```

This code here sits in a for loop, so I cannot just write the key in the `push`, it would generate the `mydata` key for every iteration of the loop.

I need to know how I can pre-define the `mydata`, has anyone got a good method to do this?

Comment: Is `results` an array or an object?

Comment: results is an object I query from an SQL db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define `mydata` as an array, and then at the end, create an object where `mydata` is one of the keys:

```
const mydata = []
for (const result in results) {
  mydata.push({
    'Num' : idnum,      
    'Status': results[result].StatusID,  
  });
}
const json = JSON.stringify({ mydata }, null, 2);
```

If you want to use a different key name, then change it when stringifying, eg:

```
const json = JSON.stringify({ someKeyName: mydata }, null, 2);
```

If `results` is an object, then you can make the code more concise with `Object.values` and `map`:

```
const Num = idnum;
const mydata = Object.values(results)
  .map((item => ({ Num, Status: item.StatusID }));
const json = JSON.stringify({ mydata }, null, 2);
fs.writeFileSync('testingjson.json', data)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works brilliantly. I will mark as correct when it allows me